# Why EP0 is disabled on USB_RESET in Atmega32u4?

Tags: usb

I use atmega32u4 (arduino pro micro), powered from usb.

In atmega32u4 datasheet p. 267 it is stated:

> When an USB reset is detected on the USB line (SE0 state with a minimum duration of 2.5μs), the next operations are performed by the controller:
>
> • all the endpoints are disabled
>
> • the default control endpoint remains configured

However, this example demonstrates that control endpoint is disabled. What is the reason of it?

```
#include <avr/io.h>

void main(void)
{
  UHWCON |= 1 << UVREGE; /* enable internal USB pads regulator */

  /* start pll */
  PLLCSR |= 1 << PINDIV;
  PLLCSR |= 1 << PLLE;
  while (!(PLLCSR & (1<<PLOCK))) ;

  /* start usb controller */
  USBCON |= 1 << USBE;
  USBCON &= ~(1 << FRZCLK);

  /* configure control endpoint */
  UENUM = 0;
  UECONX |= 1 << EPEN;
  UECFG0X = (0 << 6) | 0; /* control type, out direction */
  UECFG1X |= (2 << 4) | (0 << 2); /* size 32, one bank */
  UECFG1X |= 1 << ALLOC;


  USBCON |= 1 << OTGPADE; /* enable VBUS pad */
  while (!(USBSTA & (1 << VBUS))) ; /* wait until VBUS line detects power from host */
  UDCON &= ~(1 << DETACH); /* pull up D+ (attach) */

  while(1) {
    if (!(UECFG1X & (1 << ALLOC))) {
      DDRB |= 1 << PB0;
      PORTB |= 1 << PB0;
    }
  }
}
```

Build with:

```
avr-gcc -c -pipe -gdwarf-2 -g2 -mmcu=atmega32u4 -fshort-enums -fno-inline-small-functions -fpack-struct -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -ffunction-sections -I. -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mrelax -fno-jump-tables -x c -Os -std=gnu99 -Wstrict-prototypes test.c -o test.o
avr-gcc test.o -o test.elf -lm -Wl,-Map=test.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--relax -mmcu=atmega32u4
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock -R .signature test.elf test.hex
```

Comment: USB Reset != MCU Reset. I don't see any EP0 handling in your code for the USB reset (or otherwise), only for the MCU Power-On Reset.

Comment: @TurboJ Yes, even though there is no EP0 handling for the USB reset in my code, EP0 is reset (as is shown by the led). According to datasheet, it must not be reset. I want to find out if it is that I'm missing something or it is a bug in the hardware or datasheet.

Comment: I am confused, you must run some code to initialize USB SIE on chip reset, change the default address during enumeration, and then return to EP0 if USB_RESET is detected, all done in software. Why do you blame hardware for not doing this?

Comment: @AliChen I came to the conclusion that datasheet is false - control endpoint **is** deconfigured after a `USB_RESET` on atmega32u4. Do I need to allocate memory before attaching? (given that I need to reconfigure EP0 in end-of-reset interrupt handler anyway, memory can also be allocated there)